# Camanjs & Imagemagick - How apply same params such brightness, saturation, exposure [...]

Tags: javascript, canvas, imagemagick

I'm using camanjs to allowed user to modify an image on the fly.

Because of application's requirements I need to apply camanjs filters with imagemagick on backend. Problem is that values seems not to be applied with the same way with imagemagick I get two very diffrent images.

I tried many variation of imagemagick's -modulate command but result is still too different from what I see in browser with camanjs

For more informations about how camanjs treats each pixel see :

https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/src/lib/filters.coffee

where `adjust` is value from UI

Here is my app interface with original image on left and camanjs on right with a saturation set to 100

[image]

I apply the following command with imagemagick

**-modulate brightness[,saturation,hue]**

*The arguments are given as a percentages of variation. A value of 100 means no change, and any missing values are taken to mean 100.*

`convert football.jpg -modulate 100,200,100 football_out.jpg`

200 saturation because 100 is no change with command above so 100 in camanjs will be 200 with imagemagick

Here is football_out.jpg

[image]

As you can see saturation with imagemagick is not enough regarding result using camanjs.

There is a way to get a similar result ?

Comment: So you are doing the processing with JS, and doing the same thing again on the backend? Can you not just post the image data to the backend?

Comment: Unfortunatly no because the image modified with camanjs is not the original and is already reduced. I wanna apply the camanjs's settings on the original which is in HD.

Comment: What are the values you got when using camanjs? What are the equations used for each mode of adjustment? How do you expect anyone to answer without knowing how camanjs works and what values you used?

Comment: Value is 100 as mentioned in original post. I’m not familiar with coffee script but the equations for each filters seems to be set here https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/src/lib/filters.coffee

Comment: I also looked for the equivalent of css filters with imagemagick following the W3C specifications but the contrast CSS filter rendering did not have the same rendering with imagemagick. https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#contrastEquivalent